# how to open a link in same page in different content pane using dojo?

Tags: dojo

I have all anchor tags in left side contentpane of my web page. When i click a link, it will navigates to another another web page. i want that destination web page should open in my center contentpane.

I have hust started DOJO.Please Help me to solve this issue.

Page1
    
    
       // page1.jsp should open in this section

Comment: Could you attach and screen shot link and code??

Answer (score 1):

*Note: This example is working only for Dojo 1.8+*

Assuming that you have something similar to:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"> 
  <a href="/link1">show /link1 in targetPane</a>
  <a href="/link2">show /link2 in targetPane</a>
  ...
</div>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="targetPane"></div>
```

The basic instructions follow:

**1) Intercept `click` events on the anchors.**

For instance, you can mark the anchors you want to target the content pane with `.menuLink` class:

`<a href="/link1" class="menuLink">show /link1 in targetPane</a>`

...then for clicks on those elements:

`on(query('.menuLink'), 'click', function(e) {...})`

**2) Handle the event**

Use `e.preventDefault();` so that clicking the links won't reload the whole page (as in your current situation :)

Instead instruct the pane to load the link from the anchor:

`registry.byId('targetPane').set('href', e.target.getAttribute('href'));`

**Example**

Working example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QLvS3/5/) (since I've skipped all of the Dojo boilerplate)